# Android Studio: Layout for phone and tablet

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I finished the layout for phone and  it's working fine. Now I want to open this app on tablet too, but the layout isn't that nice. How can I make two layouts?

Thanks!

Comment: [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) should help you

Comment: I will try it, thanks!

Comment: sometime you can twitch the constraintlayout in a way that i work for both horizontal and vertial orientation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to create a tablet version of your layout in Android Studio go in Layout Design and click on the rotating device button.

A picture of what I'm talking about :

[image: menu]

This will create a copy of your layout for higher resolution.

You can also create  a Landscape version if you have vertical and horizontal orientation in your app.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem is, that the tablet version need's some more Buttons. If I write this methods, the tablet version is fine, but the phone version dosn't work anymore, because it can't find this button

Comment: Are you talking about layout or anything else?